# How do I get httpPlatformHandler and Kestrel to play nicely with multiple websites on one server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

My webserver, for development purposes, serves a couple of website. These are all hosted under xxx.example.com/yyy.example.com. Every application gets it's own subdomain but runs on the same server, which obviously lowers costs.

Trying to do this with ASP.NET 5 proves quite difficult. Kestrel seems to take over the whole socket connection instead of (somehow) IIS managing the traffic and routing it to the two different application pools and websites. The error produced by the second one is below:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.UvException: Error -4090 EADDRNOTAVAIL address not available
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.Libuv.Check(Int32 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.UvTcpHandle.Bind(ServerAddress address)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Http.TcpListener.CreateListenSocket()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Http.Listener.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<StartAsync>b__0(Object _)
```

Comment: I just created a couple of sites and ran them under IIS.  Seems to work pretty good. I recommend this article, https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html. Make sure you install the HTTP Platform Handler, and create an app pool and setting it to no managed code.

Comment: @Matthew cheers for the tips, didn't work though. AppPool is set to No Managed Code, http platform is installed (other site on same server works). Ran through the whole article to check and everything is the same.

Comment: I just installed it on a clean VM and I get exactly the same error, so it's probably something else!

Comment: I started a Github issue since for this as well (unsure if this is a configuration error or simply a bug somewhere): https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/520

Comment: Solved with the help of GuardRex on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is regarding the server.urls specified for the web command in project.json, see: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/520#issuecomment-164127476